# Adding an element to an arraylist by user

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I want to let the user  add an element to an existed arraylist and intilazied some variables that are related to the element of the arraylist, the arraylist is:

so I wrote the following code:

```
           ArrayList<FruitShop> shops= new ArrayList<FruitShop>();
           Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

            FruitShop newShop = new FruitShop(null,0.0, new Apples(), new OwnerInfo());
            shops.add(newShop);
            System.out.println("What is the name of new shop?: ");
            newShop.setShopName(int.next());;
            System.out.println("Enter initial balance in USD: ");
            newShop.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
            System.out.println("Enter owner name: ");
            newShop.getShopOwner().setName(in.next());
            System.out.println("Enter owner age: ");
            newShop.getShopOwner().setAge(Integer.parseInt(in.next()));
            System.out.println("How many apples does the store have?: ");
            newShop.getApplesInfo().setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(in.next()));
            System.out.println("What is the price of each apple?:");
            newShop.getApplesInfo().setPrice(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
            System.out.println("Your shop has been added! ");

           FruitShop.ID= ID;
            ID++;
```

the thing this is a choice from a menu " add a new fruit shop", so every time the user will add a fruit shop the object will be called newShop and then the older newShop will be deleted! how can avoid that mistake?
p.s: FruitShop is composed from to other classes: Apples and OwnerInfo
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to insert the line `shops.add(newShop);` after all `newShop` changes are done. And, of course, make `ArrayList<FruitShop> shops` as an instance variable. Don't create a new list after each call of your method.

```
public class A {
    private List<FruitShop> shops= new ArrayList<FruitShop>();

    public void addShop() {
        ...
        shops.add(newShop);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 ArrayList<FruitShop> shops= new ArrayList<FruitShop>();
           Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

            FruitShop newShop = new FruitShop(null,0.0, new Apples(), new OwnerInfo());

            System.out.println("What is the name of new shop?: ");
            newShop.setShopName(int.next());;
            System.out.println("Enter initial balance in USD: ");
            newShop.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
            System.out.println("Enter owner name: ");
            newShop.getShopOwner().setName(in.next());
            System.out.println("Enter owner age: ");
            newShop.getShopOwner().setAge(Integer.parseInt(in.next()));
            System.out.println("How many apples does the store have?: ");
            newShop.getApplesInfo().setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(in.next()));
            System.out.println("What is the price of each apple?:");
            newShop.getApplesInfo().setPrice(Double.parseDouble(in.next()));
            System.out.println("Your shop has been added! ");
             shops.add(newShop); // add last of the line when all initialization is done.
```

> Shift your statement `shops.add(newShop);` at last. After initialization is  getting done.